# Angular interpolate inside a component like mat-checkbox

Tags: html, angular

So I want to have a `mat-checkbox` component with a HTML string inside the label.

I tried the following:

```
<mat-checkbox class="check">
    {{ someHtml }}
</mat-checkbox>
```

But it prints the HTML string as a string and doesn't render it.

Using the following doesn't work either:

```
<mat-checkbox class="check" [innerHtml]="someHtml">
</mat-checkbox>
```

This just replaces the whole content, including the checkbox that gets generated at runtime. Is there any way to inject the html into the label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Angular Directives](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives)
The idea here is to fetch the element from the HTML, then append some raw HTML dynamically.

Supose this scenario

app.component.html

```
<mat-checkbox class="check" [appendHtml]="innerHtml"></mat-checkbox>
```

app.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  innerHtml = `<div style="border: 1px solid red;"> Text inside </div>`;
  constructor() {}
}
```

As you can see, I added a `appendHtml` attribute to the `mat-checkbox` element. This is a custom directive that expects a string as "raw" HTML.

append-html.directive.ts

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appendHtml]'
})
export class AppendHtmlDirective implements AfterViewInit {
  @Input('appendHtml') html: string

  constructor(private element: ElementRef) {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const d = this.element.nativeElement.querySelector('label');
    d.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', this.html);
  }
}
```

The `AppendHtmlDirective` expects an `html` property of type string and implements `AfterViewInit` interface (from Angular) to fetch the element once it is rendered. By injection, Angular provides us the element which is being applied; so, the `ElementRef` from the constructor is our `MatCheckbox` element, in that case.
We can use the `insertAdjacentHTML` function to append childs to the element. I just fetched the `label` element from the `MatCheckbox` to fit inside of it. In every case, you should see where to append the HTML.
I mean, `label` here works, bc `MatCheckbox` has a tag whitin matching that. If you want to reuse this Directive for other elements, you should be passing the literal to find inside.
i.e.:
append-hmtl.directive.ts

```
// ...
@Input() innerSelector: string
// ...
 ngAfterViewInit() {
    const d = this.element.nativeElement.querySelector(this.innerSelector);
    d.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', this.html);
 }
```

app.component.hmtl

```
<mat-checkbox class="check" [appendHtml]="innerHtml" innerSelector="label"></mat-checkbox>
```

Moreover, you can pass as many inputs as you need to customize the styling or behavior of your directive.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just wrap everything in a div and put it on the outside.

```
<div>
<mat-checkbox class="check"> </mat-checkbox>
{{ someHtml }}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. This removes the functionality of mat-checkbox, so not really a preferrable solution, but that is what I would have resorted to if there is no other way. just with `[innerHtml]` because otherwise the html wont show

Answer (score 0):

You can just put a span in the mat-checkbox :

```
<mat-checkbox class="check">
    <span [appendHtml]="innerHtml"></span>
</mat-checkbox>
```